# Copy most of the field values from one object to the other

Tags: apex

So i have two copies of an object and i want to copy over most but not all of the fields from one to the other.  Luckily, i use naming conventions to help, all the fields i need to copy over start with `Assets` or `Banking` so this is what im playing with

```
Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> MeetingFields = Schema.SObjectType.Meeting__c.fields.getMap();

for(String key : MeetingFields.keySet()) {

   if (key.startsWith('Assets') || key.startsWith('Banking')  ) {
       meeting[key] = prevMeeting.get(key);
   }

}
```

the two objects, meeting and prevMeeting are both Meeting__c sObjects..

It does loop through all the fields and key is fine but how do i get the key from each object to do the copy?

I tried

```
meeting[key] = prevMeeting.get(key);
meeting.get(key) = prevMeeting.get(key);
```

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [SObject.put()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_put) method.

```
Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> MeetingFields = Schema.SObjectType.Meeting__c.fields.getMap();

for(String key : MeetingFields.keySet()) {

   if (key.startsWith('Assets') || key.startsWith('Banking')  ) {
       meeting.put(key, prevMeeting.get(key));
   }

}
```

Comment: Duh!  thanks for this.  Do you know offhand if the .get() method will get a fields value even if its not in the original query that build the object or will it only get existing field values

Comment: No, it won't. You'll get an exception.